# MySQL join a different table based on field value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table containing the last comments posted on the website, and I'd like to join a different table depending on the comment `type`.

`Comments` Table is similar to this structure:

```
id | type | ressource_id |
---+------+--------------+
1  |  1   |      10      |
2  |  3   |       7      |
```

What I'd like to do is to join the "News" table if type `type = 1` (`on news.id = comments.ressource_id`), "tutorial" table if type `type = 3`, etc.

How can I do this please? I've tried different queries using `CASE` and `UNION`, but never got the expected results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `left outer join` and a `on` clause matching on the `type`:

```
select coalesce(n.id, t.id) id
,      c.type
,      c.resource_id
from   comments c
left
outer
join   news n
on     n.id = comments.resource_id
and    c.type = 1
left
outer
join   tutorial t
on     t.id = comments.resource_id
and    c.type = 3
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick answer, it works like a charm! I also tried something with `coalesce` before, but forgot the `OUTER JOIN`, it makes sense now.

Comment: Just came here to say thanks, found this after googling and was exactly what I needed to change the data based on an ID :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with unioned queries assuming that you can coerce partial queries into producing a similar schema, along the lines of:

```
select n.id as id, c.something as something
    from news n, comments c
    where n.type = 1
    and   n.id = c.resource_id
union all
select n.id as id, t.something as something
    from news n, tutorial t
    where n.type = 3
    and   n.id = t.resource_id
```

In other words, the first query simply joins `news` and `comments` for rows where `news.type` indicates a comment, and the second query joins `news` and `tutorials` for rows where `news.type` indicates a tutorial.

Then the union combined the two into a single record set.

I'd steer clear of `case` in this situation (and many others) since it almost always invariably requires per-row modification of the data, which rarely scales wee. Running two queries and combining the results is usually more efficient.